# Example of Violation Of Newton's Laws of Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames

Can anybody give an everyday example, that is, places where Newton's 3 laws of motion fail? I searched on this site, but it only answers for the 3rd law of motion

I recently read in a book, that Newton's law can fail in a circular motion. But it doesn't explain.

So, can anybody explain daily-life examples of the violation of Newton's 3 laws?

**Newton's 1st law states that** - *An object at rest or moving with constant velocity in a straight line will remain so until an external force is applied to it.*

I do not think this law will ever fail. But If you know a situation where it will fail, please tell!

**Newton's 2nd law** - *Newton's second law of motion pertains to the behaviour of objects for which all existing forces are not balanced.*

**Newton's 3rd law** - *For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction.*

Can anyone explain the examples?

Comment: Are you asking about non-inertial frames?

Comment: I do not know about that? Please tell me some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, Newton's laws of motion are true in inertial frames.

Consider you are in an elevator moving with a constant velocity downwards. Assume you have spring measure. Clearly here third law is valid. The spring is balancing the body's weight $mg$ using a force $kx$ upwards the body is applying a force $mg$ on the spring and the spring applies same force.

On the other hand, consider the elevator is moving with a constant acceleration $a$ upward, the extension of the spring is clearly not $\frac{kx}{m}$  and the spring is applying a force $m(g+a)$ on the body but body mass cannot apply anymore force than $mg$. The third law isn't quite valid. It gets valid if a pseudoforce $ma$ is assumed on the body in the opposite direction of acceleration.

Similarly we can say that in a circular motion (accelerated normal to the motion) third law of motion isn't quite valid unless we assume a pseudoforce in the outward direction called centrifugal force.

Comment: Frames which are not accelerated are called inertial frames

Answer (score 4):

As far as we know, Newtons laws always hold true provided you apply them in the right way. In particular, you must be careful to about what sort of frame of reference you use to quantify the positions and movements of objects. For example, if you tried to play a game of billiards on a cruise liner, say, then while the liner was in uniform motion, the billiard balls would obey Newton's laws. But if the ship suddenly changed direction, then when viewed from the reference frame of the ship, the balls would appear to accelerate of their own volition on the table, thus seeming to violate Newton's laws. Of course, if you take account of the fact that the ship is accelerating, you will realise that the balls are indeed continuing to obey the laws- it is just that their movement with respect to the ship seems to suggest otherwise.

So, the key principles, about bodies staying at rest or in uniform motion unless forces apply to them, are true provided that you consider the motion from a reference frame that is not itself accelerating in some way.

If you measure the motion of objects with respect to an accelerating reference frame, then Newton's laws can't be applied directly. For example, if you get in your car and accelerate up the street, you could pick your car as the frame of reference from which you will measure the motion of everything around you- you will take your car to be stationary and the buildings and people around you appear to be accelerating away from you, apparently in violation of Newton's laws.